# Classes reading one word from file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

This is my program and it supposed to get text word by word from file `Team.txt` but it says it can't open the file. I tried showing directory directly to the file still the same answers. I think I got something here:

```
class Team
    {
        public:
        string name;
        string dificulty;
        string section;
    };



void GetTeamInfo(class Team);

    int main()
    {   
        Team ko;
        GetTeamInfo(ko);
        cout << ko.name;
        cout << ko.dificulty;
        cout << ko.section;
        system("PAUSE");
    }

void GetTeamInfo(Team)
    {
        std::ifstream fd;
        fd.open("Team.txt");
        Team ko;
        if (fd.is_open())
        {
            fd >> ko.name;
            fd >> ko.dificulty;
            fd >> ko.section;

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Mistake can't open file 'Team.txt'\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Verify that the file Team.txt exists and is in the right directory, try giving it a full path instead (remember to escape slashes). Make sure your process has permission to open the file.

Comment: Check the current folder from your program. There's no C++-standard API for that that I know of, but there's the POSIX `getcwd()` (or its Windows version, `_getcwd()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because your argument handling is all wrong.

The declaration

```
void GetTeamInfo(Team)
```

tells the compiler that `GetTeamInfo` is a function which takes an argument of type `Team`, but you don't give it a name so you can't use the argument anywhere inside the function.

If you want to use the passed argument you should give it a name:

```
void GetTeamInfo(Team ko)
```

You then don't have to declare the variable `ko` inside the function.

However, this is not going to work anyway, because arguments are by default passed *by value*, that means arguments are copies of the values from the caller. And changing a copy will of course not change the original. So what you should do it pass the argument *by reference*:

```
void GetTeamInfo(Team& ko)
```

---

All of this is *very* basic C++ knowledge, and any good book or tutorial should have learned you this very early.

---

As for the problem of the program not being able to open your file, there are multiple possible causes for that problem:

- Your IDE (Integrated Development Environment) is having one current directory for your program, and the file is not in that directory. This can be changed with project settings.
- The file is actually not where you think it is.
- The file simply doesn't exist.
- On systems such as Linux and Mac OSX filenames are case sensitive, and the actual file doesn't have a capital `'T'` in its name.

Comment: @Blank I tend to write my answers very iteratively, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But then I get error that says GetTeamInfo(ko) in int main() doesent match

Comment: @Blank The declaration (prototype) before `main` must of course match the actual function definition.

Comment: Men I apreciate for what you did. You helped me hell a lot. Thank you very very much. Im almost crying couse its working thank you man again. Love you <3 #noHomo